# RF Power Supplies - Matching Impedance

Tags: rf, interface

I'll soon be working with RF Power Supplies used to provide power to plasma generators and other systems. A 50 ohm resistive load is used. If I'm correct, in most cases matching impedance between RF supply and load will result in maximum power transfer. It is also a goal to reduce ghosting and reflective foldback (power reflected back into supply). Can someone with more knowledge on the subject explain the theory of how and why ghosting occurs in such a system and how reflective foldback is best minimized?

Answer (score 0):

As you say, by matching the impedances. I'm not sure what your actual question is.

If you're asking how to match impedances when you don't know what they are *a priori*, then that's what various types of [RF matching networks](http://leleivre.com/rf_lcmatch.html) are for. You use a [VSWR meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWR_meter) to monitor the ratio of reflected power to forward power as you adjust the network.

Comment: I am new to the technology and I will be trained by experienced engineers and techs - just trying to understand a bit of RF theory and practice before starting. Thank you for the links - they will help me get started exploring RF.